# Connect to IPsec VPN using OpenSwan

Tags: networking, vpn, nat, ipsec, openswan

I'm connected to Internet with a simple ADSL router with NAT. I have a smartphone and a laptop running linux.

I need to connect to a IPsec server using OpenSwan. First I tested that it is possible to connect to. I entered connection info into the smartphone and connection was established through the router. Now I see that router is not a problem. And I start to connect my linux laptop:

```
# ipsec auto --up witopia
104 "witopia" #1: STATE_MAIN_I1: initiate
010 "witopia" #1: STATE_MAIN_I1: retransmission; will wait 20s for response
010 "witopia" #1: STATE_MAIN_I1: retransmission; will wait 40s for response
010 "witopia" #1: STATE_MAIN_I1: retransmission; will wait 40s for response
...
```

My configuration file `/etc/ipsec.d/witopia.conf`:

```
conn witopia
    left=%defaultroute
    leftid=@witopia
    leftmodecfgclient=yes
    leftxauthclient=yes
    leftxauthusername=W\johnsmith@gmail.com
    right=ipsec.sanfrancisco.witopia.net
    rightxauthserver=yes
    rightmodecfgserver=yes
    authby=secret
    auto=add
```

What could be wrong here?